# data type not updating in mySQL Workbench

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysql-workbench, alter-table

I cant seem to be able to change the datatype of my "first_name" column, I would like it to be VARCHAR(45), but it's not changing from INT(11) as seen in the diagram table and connection below.

[image: Diagram picture of table] [image: Connection picture]

I have tried to forward engineer the diagram several times, but it does not update from the initial first "iteration" of what is shown in the right-hand picture.

**update:**
I have tried to delete the files, and rewriting the tables and forward engineering them with the correct information and it still doesn't change from an integer.... arghh.

Posted my code below:

**PHP:**

```php
<?php

    //connection information
    $client = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $key = "root";
    $dbname = "formDB";


    // Attempt MySQL server connection
    $connection = new mysqli($client, $user, $key, $dbname);


    // Check connection
    if($connection === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Escape user inputs for security
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['last_name']);
    $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email_address']);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";

    if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully!";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR! not able to execute: <br> $sql <br> " . mysqli_error($connection);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>form to db</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- create form -->
    <form class="details" action="insert.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <label for="first_name"> First name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address">
      </p>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: MySQL Workbench is one of the most buggiest applications I have ever seen. That’s why I propose to check everything in a real mySQL query like explain table before searching for any error that might be only a bug in the workbench

Comment: I am a newbie to SQL, how would that syntax look like?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use the following syntax to change the datatype of an existing column:

```
alter table person modify first_name varchar(45);
```

There should not be conversion problems turning an `int(11)` to a `varchar(45)`, even if your data contains data already.

Comment: yes, I agree. I want it to be a string, my issue is that it doesn't update from an integer to a string when I am telling mySQL-Workbench to. I am using PHP though, would I be able to query your solution through PHP maybe?
like this:
`ALTER TABLE person MODIFY first_name VARCHAR(45);`

Comment: @crud: my bad, I read your requirement the other way around. Yes, that's the correct syntax. I updated my answer.

Comment: It still does not want to change to a string, perhaps I am doing something wrong. I will update my post to include my code. I might have some flaws there..

Comment: @crud: here is a demo that shows that this does work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59c692a4da764d86d3fcf4b1b51e4fde

Comment: As long as you check the type in Workbench you will have no success. Please learn yourself to use the mysql CLI. Then you are able to access mysql directly without any script or application which might cause problems